# async await on Jquery ajax callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm trying to do this with `async/await`, but any solution is good. Anyone know how I could change this:

```
series[group].forEach(async (ele, j) => {
    await $.ajax({
        url: `templates/ele${ele}.template.html`,
        success: function (data) {
          const $copyEl = $(el).clone()
          const r = new RegExp('\\{\\{\\s*' + item + '\\s*\\}\\}', 'g')
          const html = $copyEl.html().replace(r, data)

          $(html).insertBefore(parent)
        },
        error: function (e) {
          console.error(e)
        }           
      }).then(() => {
        $(parent).detach()
        if(i + 1 === outer_last && j + 1=== inner_last)
          template_callback()
      })
  })
})
```

to not run the `.detach()` until after the last `.insertBefore()` completes?

Comment: `forEach` is synchronous. It doesn't know about async functions. Also, mixing `await` and promises is strange.

Comment: hmm, I thought that you _can_ do `foo.forEach(async...)` (to block on each interation) but not `async foo.forEach(...)` (to block on the whole `forEach` loop).. in any case, my concern here is for the ajax callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map each of the elements in your array to `Promise`s, and then rely on `Promise.all`:

```
const promises = series[group].map((ele) => (
    $.ajax({
        url: `templates/ele${ele}.template.html`,
    }).then((data) => {
        const $copyEl = $(el).clone()
        const r = new RegExp('\\{\\{\\s*' + item + '\\s*\\}\\}', 'g')
        const html = $copyEl.html().replace(r, data)

        $(html).insertBefore(parent)
    }, (e) => {
        console.error(e)
    })
))

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  $(parent).detach()
})
```

Comment: Wait, is `Promise.all` doing anything for me? I need to wait until `insertBefore` completes, not the outer ajax call.

Comment: Sorry, let me fix up my code. I didn't realize you had a `success` method.

Comment: @robertotomás Try the changes now.

Comment: umm, curly braces `series[group].map((ele) => {` not parens! and, it still does not work (I get no rendered templates at all that way, whereas I get most of them but occassionally not one .. usually the first or last in a series

Comment: Oh the parens are intended, as the function will automatically return that value without the return keyword. It's nice for single statement lambdas.

Comment: Also, do you mind giving the HTML that is currently on the page and what is generated? It seems like you're referring to variables that don't exist in your code.

Comment: those lambdas got it for me, good job. :) restored mark as answer. the code is (not yet in latest form now) at https://github.com/robbiemu/cmst301-project2 - look at the scripts/presentation.js -- presentation for class. You can look at the current version here: https://cmst301-project2.herokuapp.com